# Add a Key for Request Body in JMeter

Tags: json, jmeter

I am running a Performance Test in JMeter
So in my case I need to give a Request Body as a Json String along with a key called 'json'

I cant find a way on JMeter to provide a key when passing the Request Body like Postman
ex : Key              Value
     json             {some JSON String}

What I have tried in JMeter :

[image]

Postman API Call :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just switch to "Parameters" tab where you will have Postman-like style definition of the request parameters in form of name-value pairs

[image]

Going forward, given you can successfully execute the request in Postman you should be able to record the request using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html), just [configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy](https://support.getpostman.com/hc/en-us/articles/360008893713-How-do-I-configure-Postman-to-work-through-a-proxy-):

[image]

and if your request assumes `test.pdf` file upload make sure to [copy this file to the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter/)